# MSI setup auto copying Shell32.dll, causing problems

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll

The application need to use COM reference `Microsoft Shell Control And Automation`, which is  located at `C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll`

But after adding its reference, VS 2010 added a dll `Interop.Shell32.DLL` in target build directory. Everything working fine. But when builing MSI setup wizard project. It adds `shell32.dll` as dependency. Alright, No problem.

But when install, it also copies `shell32.dll` along with `Interop.Shell32.DLL` in target installation directory, now when application runs it shows strange errors. But if I manually delete `shell32` from installation directory, everything works fine.

Why MSI is copying `shell32.dll` in installation directory ? Is it required for 64-bit OS ? If yes, why`Interop.Shell32.DLL` ?
For my app, `shell32.dll` seems to be problem, Is there a way I can avoid it being copied ?

Edit:

I excluded `shell32.dll` from setup project, will it be problem in 64bit OS ?

Edit2:
`shell32.dll` at `C:\Windows\system32\` is actually 5KB but MSI copies 11 MB one. What is it ?

Answer (score 2):

You will definitely have to prevent your installer from copying shell32.dll.  It is a critical operating system DLL that is *always* included with Windows.  Having the wrong version of shell32.dll is a rather fatal problem.  The file system protection feature built into Windows will prevent it from overwriting the one in c:\windows\system32, but it is powerless to stop a local copy from ruining your program.  And yes, it is many megabytes, it only *looks* like it is installed in c:\windows\system32.  That's actually a hard-link to the real location, it is stored in c:\windows\winsxs.  Most files in system32 are actually hard links, otherwise a simple mechanism to prevent bad installers from destroying the operating system.

The Interop.Shell32.dll assembly is an interop assembly, generated by Tlbimp.exe.  It only contains declarations with the [ComImport] directive, the ones retrieved from the type library inside shell32.dll and translated to equivalent .NET declarations.  Gives the CLR an easy time to implement the RCW without it having to read the type library itself.  You *do* have to deploy the interop assembly.

No idea what went wrong here, it certainly isn't normal for an installer creator utility to automatically also copy the native DLL for the interop assembly.  But you do have to intervene and stop it from doing this.

Comment: Yes it does copy Interop.Shell32.dll everywhere, this assembly was never a problem. Problem came with shell32.dll. It gets auto merged with msi and copied at installation directory. I managed to excluded it from msi. I hope it doesnt crash on 64 bit OS.

Comment: Murphy's Law ensures that untested code always crashes on another machine.

Comment: True, I have tested on Win 8 64 bit, both works fine, with shell32.dll and without. Havent tested with win 7.

Answer (score 1):

You could add reference and then set the properties of this reference

set **copy local** to False

Comment: shell32.dll never copies in Build directory, but only after installation, MSI copies it there.

Comment: This is not correct, Copy Local = True is required to get the interop assembly copied to the same directory as the EXE.  The program just won't run without it.